# Binding the interface with class in mvc3 EF

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, class, interface

Suppose I have some Interface like :

```
public interface IIconComponent
{
   // statements ...
}
```

then I am implementing this interface within my class as below

```
public class IconComponent : IIconcomponent
{
   // implementing the interface statements ..
}
```

and creating a Table in mvc3 like:

```
public class IconDBContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<IIconComponent> Icon {get; set;} //Is this statement possible 
}
```

That is making the set of objects of interface type for storing the class IconComponent objects in the table. How to do this in MVC3 ?

Does I have to implement some model-binder for this ? or, there exists some other method ?

Thanking you,

Answer (score 2):

EF doesn't support interfaces. `DbSet` must be defined with the real implementation. Once you change it to use implementation your actions will most probably use it as well because there will be no reason to work with abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use entity framework is you're creating abstraction layer on top of it, it's as you're not using entity framework at all and because of that entity framework is not able to work with interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to, you can let your Entity Framework classes implement interfaces. With POCO's it's straightforward, with edmx you can make partial classes that contain the derivation from the interface. However, as said by Ladislav, something like `DbSet<IIconComponent>` is not possible.

I can imagine scenarios where you would want to use this, e.g. dealing with other application components that only accept specific interfaces, but that you want to populate with your EF classes. (The other day, I did exactly that with a legacy UI layer).